# Django - edit both sides of a many-to-many relation with generic UpdateView

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-related-manager

I have a question whether or not it is possible to use the generic UpdateView class to edit "both sides" of a many-to-many relationship.
I have the following classes defined in models.py:

```
class SomeCategory(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)    


class SomeClass(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=False)
    age = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    allowed_categories = models.ManyToManyField(SomeCategory)
```

These are both dictionary type tables that store sets of configuration data for my application. To allow editing the dictionaries I use simple UpdateViews:

```
class SomeClassUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = SomeClass
    template_name = 'admin/edit_class.html'
    fields = ['code', 'name', 'age', 'allowed_categories']
    ordering = ['code']
```

This works fine, I get a nice multi-select and everything is perfect. However, I would like to have the possibility to edit the relationship from the side of the SomeCategory table, so I can choose which SomeClass elements are linked to a certain SomeCategory:

```
class SomeCategoryUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = SomeCategory
    template_name = 'admin/edit_category.html'
    fields = ['code', 'name',  ??????? ]
    ordering = ['code']
```

I have tried adding the `related_name` attribute to the SomeCategory model, but that did not work.

Any ideas if this can be done without using a custom ModelForm?

Key library versions:

```
Django==1.11.8
psycopg2==2.7.4
```

PS: this is my very first question asked on stackoverflow, so please let me know if my post is missing any mandatory elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is in the models.py file. You have two classes, but only one of them mentions the other one. You would think that this should be enough since you are using `ManyToManyField` after all and assume that it would automatically create every connection leading both ways... Unfortunately this is not true. On the database level it does indeed create a separate intermediary table with references to objects in both original tables, but that doesn't mean that both of them will be automatically visible in Django Admin or similar.

If you would attempt to simply create another `someclass = models.ManyToManyField(SomeClass)` in the `SomeCategory` class that would fail. Django would try to create another separate intermediary table **through** which the connection between two main tables is established. But because the name of the intermediary table depends on where you define the `ManyToManyField` connection, the second table would be created with a different name and everything would just logically collapse (two tables having two separate **default** ways to have a ManyToMany connection makes no sense).

The solution is to add a `ManyToManyField` connection to `SomeCategory` while also referencing that intermediary/through table that was originally created in the `SomeClass` class.

A couple of notes about Django/python/naming/programming conventions:

- Use the name of the table you are referencing to, as the name of the field that is containing the info about that connection. Meaning that `SomeClass`'s field with a link to `SomeCategory` should be named `somecategory` instead of `allowed_categories`.
- If the connection is one-to-many - use singular form; if the connection is many-to-many - use plural. Meaning that in this case we should use plural and use `somecategories` instead of `somecategory`.
- Django can automatically pluralize names, but it does it badly - it simply adds `s` letter to the end. `Mouse` -> `Mouses`, `Category` -> `Categorys`. In those kind of cases you have to help it by defining the `verbose_name_plural` in the special `Meta` class.
- Using references to other classes without extra `'`s works only if the the class was already defined previously in the code. In the case of two classes referring to each other that is true only one way. The solution is to put the name of the referred class in the quotation marks like `'SomeCategory'` instead of `SomeCategory`. This sort of reference, called a `lazy relationship`, can be useful when resolving circular import dependencies between two applications. And since by default it's better to keep the style the same and to avoid unnecessary brain energy wasting of "I will decide whether or not to use quotation marks depending on the order the classes have been organized; I will have to redo this quotation marks thingie every time I decide to move some code pieces around" I recommend that you simply use quotation marks every time. Just like when learning to drive a car - it's better to learn to always use turn signals instead of first looking around and making a separate decision of whether someone would benefit from that information.
- "Stringifying" (lazy loading) model/class/table name is easy - just add `'`s around. You would think that stringifying the "through" table reference would work the same easy way. And you would be wrong - it will give you the `ValueError: Invalid model reference. String model references must be of the form 'app_label.ModelName'.` error. In order to reference the stringified "through" table you need to: (a) add `'`s around; (b) replace all dots (`.`) with underscores (`_`); (c) delete the reference to `through`!.. So `SomeClass.somecategories.through` becomes `'SomeClass_somecategories'`.

Therefore the solution is this:

```
class SomeCategory(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    someclasses = models.ManyToManyField('SomeClass', through='SomeClass_somecategories', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'SomeCategories'


class SomeClass(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=False)
    age = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    somecategories = models.ManyToManyField('SomeCategory')
```

After this it should be obvious what kind of final changes to make to your `UpdateView` classes.

Comment: I am just trying to apply this. Thanks for the clear explanation. For me this results in a new database table '<app>_somecategory_someclasses', which would indicate that the reverse relationship is being maintained separately to the original one, which isn't the desired behavior. You think I've done something wrong or has behavior changed? (I love your learning to drive analogy, btw)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in the view and form, without having to specify the additional `ManytoMany` connections in the
models, using something like the following:

**In the View**

```
class SomeClassUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = SomeClass
    form_class = SomeClassUpdateForm  # to specify the form
    template_name = 'admin/edit_class.html'
    
        def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
            initial_somecategorys = SomeCategory.objects.filter(allowed_categories__pk=form.instance.pk)
            amended_somecategorys = form.cleaned_data['allowed_categroies']
            remove = [x for x in initial_somecategorys if x not in amended_somecategorys]
            add = [x for x in amended_somecategorys if x not in initial_somecategorys]
            for somecategory in add:
                somecategory.allowed_categories.add(form.instance)
                somecategory.save()
            for somecategory in remove:
                somecategory.allowed_categories.remove(form.instance)
                somecategory.save()
            return super().form_valid(form)
```

**In the Form**

The init method at the top pre-populates the form with entries saved on the model.

```
class SomeClassUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SomeClassUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            obj = kwargs['instance']
            self.fields["some_categories"].initial = SomeCategory.objects.filter(allowed_categories__pk=form.instance.pk)
        except (AttributeError, KeyError):  # to catch NoneType if new entry being created.
            pass

    some_categories = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        required=False,
        queryset=SomeCategory.objects.all(),
    )
    
    class Meta:
        model = SomeClass
        fields = [
        'some_categories'
        ..etc 
        ]
```

This should work. I've writen similar code in one of my projects, and it's working fine. However, I don't know if it's
structurally best to use methods like this and not alter the model relationships or whether it's preferable to
alter the model relationships as outlined in other replies. So I'd be interested to know other peoples views on what
the best approach is.